# Fill array regardless if there is empty check

Tags: php, laravel

So I have the following code:

```php
if ($obj->updated_date > $record->updated_date || $mode === 'refresh') {
    if (empty($obj->birthday) || $obj->hire_date) {
        $record->fill([
            'birthday' => '',
            'hire_date' => ''
        ]);
    } else {
        $record->fill($arr);
    }
} else {
    $record->timestamps = false;
}
```

Where I'm checking if `$obj->birthday or $obj->hire_date` is empty, and then define them as empty strings, but here is the problem.

I want to be able to call `$record->fill($arr)` regardless and prepopulate all my fields on the empty check, but for some reason I can't seem to figure out out.

So heres the logic:

Empty hire_date? set as ''.
Empty birthday? set as ''.
Populate the rest of the fields..

Both hire_date and birthday not empty? Populate all fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if ($obj->updated_date > $record->updated_date || $mode === 'refresh') {
    $filllArray = $arr;
    if (empty($obj->birthday) {
        $record->fill([
            'birthday' => ''
        ]);
        unset($filllArray['birthday']);
    }
    if (empty($obj->hire_date)) {
        $record->fill([
            'hire_date' => ''
        ]);
        unset($filllArray['hire_date']);
    }
    $record->fill($filllArray);
} else {
    $record->timestamps = false;
}
```

Update 1: Copy the `$arr` to `$filllArray` and update the new array to determine what should be filled or not.

Comment: seems like the `$record->fill($arr);` ends up overwritting the results.

Comment: @Tripp Okay, I've updated my answer according to your comment. That should handle all your cases.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've accepted an answer. This is a slightly different way of achieving the same thing (If I understood the question correctly)

```
if ($obj->updated_date > $record->updated_date || $mode === 'refresh') {
    $fa = [];
    empty($obj->birthday) ? $fa['birthday'] = '' : $fa['birthday'] = $obj->birthday;
    empty($obj->hire_date) ? $fa['hire_date'] = '' : $fa['hire_date'] = $obj->hire_date;
    $merged_arr = array_merge($arr, $fa);
    $record->fill($merged_arr);    
} else {
    $record->timestamps = false;
}
```